# How to trigger SQL Server database/table error messages from VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to trigger SQL Server error messages while executing a stored procedure.

Example

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_TableX_$RateCard_Box". The conflict occurred in database "TestDB", table "dbo.TableX".

I want to know if this error trigger in procedure, how can I popup meaningful message to user.

I execute the SQL Server stored procedure from VB.net.

Comment: you can use try and catch in your stored procedure and can raise the custom error/message as per your requirement  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Mukesh Arora - Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use `TRY CATCH` statements and throw `Message`, `Severity` and `State` in `CATCH` statement:

```
BEGIN TRY
    -- Your code here...            
END TRY   

BEGIN CATCH             
    DECLARE @Message varchar(MAX) = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @Severity int = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @State smallint = ERROR_STATE()

    RAISERROR(@Message, @Severity, @State)
END CATCH
```